# @RequestBody coming null in @RestController for post request in spring boot 1.2.1

Tags: spring, rest, post, request

I am following Book Rest Controller by Balaji Varanasi  Apress publication Chapter4  Beginning QuickPoll Application.and my Vote Controller class is not working.Poll Controller work correct for posting question and other Rest operations.so my basic setup is correct for rest service.
VoteController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/polls/{pollId}/votes",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createVote(@RequestBody Vote vote,@PathVariable Integer pollId)
{
    vote= voteRepository.save(vote);
    //SET THE HEADERS FOR NEWLY CREATED RESOURCE
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders  = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setLocation(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(vote.getId()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null,responseHeaders,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}}
```

Option domain:

```
@Entity
public class Option {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="OPTN_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="OPTN_SEQ", sequenceName="OPTN_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="OPTION_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="OPTION_VALUE")
    private String value;
```

Vote domain:

```
@Entity
public class Vote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="VOTE_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="VOTE_SEQ", sequenceName="VOTE_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="VOTE_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne//(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="OPTION_ID")
    @OrderBy
    private Option option;
```

removed setter/getter for posting.
Vote domain has many to one relationship with Option.
I am sending below Post request from postman.poll id is coming correct but vote is null

```
    http://localhost:8081/polls/1/votes
    {
      "option":{"id": 14,"value": "Bihar" }
    }
```

could you please help to know why request body is not coming to Rest Controller

Comment: How did you determin that it is "not working"? What happens instead?

Comment: In my voteController,createVote method.public ResponseEntity<?> createVote(@RequestBody Vote vote,@PathVariable Integer pollId).pollId is populating correct but vote is coming null and save fails with error 
"java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BATMAN"."VOTE"."OPTION_ID")" That is becuase Option attribute of vote in my method is null.as I send in requiest body.I expect option id 14 and value Bihar